# How to check if a configuration option is changed

Tags: php, configuration, settings, configuration-files, ini

I would like to know how to check if a configuration option is changed or not in PHP.

Currently I am using [`ini_get_all()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ini-get-all.php) which almost works:

```
// Change the error_log directive
ini_set('error_log', '/tmp/php.log');
$settings = array_filter(ini_get_all(), function ($item) {
  return ($item['access'] !== INI_SYSTEM);
});
foreach ($settings as $key => $value) {
  if ($value['local_value'] !== $value['global_value']) {
    echo $key . ' is modified<br />';
  }
}
```

However, when a default value for an option is **not** set in the configuration file it seems like both `local_value` and `global_value` will be set to the same value when overridden. Looking on the `phpinfo()` the master value for these setting is displayed as `no value`.

I was also trying to use [`get_cfg_var()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-cfg-var.php), but did not get it to work as I wanted:

```
// Change the error_log directive
ini_set('error_log', '/tmp/php.log');
$settings = array_filter(ini_get_all(), function ($item) {
  return ($item['access'] !== INI_SYSTEM);
});
foreach ($settings as $key => $value) {
  if (get_cfg_var($key) !== $value['local_value']) {
    echo $key . ' is modified<br />';
  }
}
```

Comment: The `$item['access'] !== INI_SYSTEM` makes no sense to me, won't that return true for everything? Changing it to `$item['global_value'] !== $item['local_value'];` seems to work for me, it'll reveal that error_log is modified

Comment: @zanderwar -  I am using `ini_get_all()` to get all configuration options and then the `array_filter()` to remove items which can only be set in the `php.ini` file. I am **not** using it to check if the value has been modified? Also, if you read my question I am clearly stating that it works for values which **are** set (not empty) in the default configuration, so my guess would be that you have a setting in your `php.ini` for `error_log`. Try the same for a setting which is reported by `phpinfo()` as `no value` and you see what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

`global_value` not is original value

it's bad code! but it working:

```
<?php

ini_set('error_log', '/tmp/abcdefg.log');
$settings = array_filter(ini_get_all(), function ($item) {
    return ($item['access'] !== INI_SYSTEM);
});
foreach ($settings as $key => $value) {
    $local = ini_get($key);
    ini_restore($key);
    $global = ini_get($key);
    ini_set($key, $local);

    if ($local !== $global) {
        echo $key . ' is modified'."\n";
    }
}
```

or use [this function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php#106862) to parse `phpinfo()` output

Comment: Well this might work, but seems a little bit hackish =) Hopefully there is a better way of doing this.

Comment: It'll drop some deprecation notices depending on your version and some warnings depending on what's in your ini (zend opcache for example)

Comment: @zanderwar - what deprecation warnings would that be?

Comment: The only reason you get a warning is because you are trying to set an option which is deprecated. This is obviously how `ini_set()` works and not a problem.

Comment: The point remains, this code will drop deprecation notices and warnings... as mentioned: `depending on what's in your ini`